# Gather/Extract first Bit from Integer Array

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, intrinsics, instructions

## Problem

Does an instruction exist that gathers/extracts the first bit of an `int[32]` and stores it into a `int`?

- I know about the intrinsic `pext` but that is not really what I want.
- I do have a code for that but I thought maybe there a designated instruction.
- The `ints` array is zero besides the first bit. Ergo, no masking needed.

## Code

```cpp
void ints2bits(int &bits, int *ints) {
   bits = (ints[0] << 0) + (ints[1] << 1) + ... + (ints[31] << 31);
}
```

## *UPDATE & FEEDBACK*:

Just tested harold suggestions. It works very well and I can attain nice speed up.

Comment: If you want to extract first bit of all  31 integers of array and a store the bits  at appropriate place in an int, then you code is wrong.

Comment: It is not wrong. I literally use it. The question is only if there is a specific instruction for this operation. Masking of the array is not needed by the way, which is maybe the reason you claim its faultiness.

Comment: Your code assumes that all the other bits in the ints are zero, you should probably state that explicitly in your problem specification.

Comment: Why did you edit your question without accepting harold's answer?  It's still the correct answer: vector left shift -> `movmskps` does exactly what you're asking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no single instruction that can even read that much data, but groups of 4 (8 with AVX2) can be processed quickly with the use of `_mm_movemask_ps`. Ignore the fact that it claims to be a floating point instruction, it just gathers and appends the 4 top bits.

Of course moving the bottom bit into the top is easy with `_mm_slli_epi32`.

So putting it together (not tested)

```
int res = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i += 4) {
    __m128i x = _mm_load_si128((__m128i*)&ints[i]); // I assume it's aligned
    x = _mm_slli_epi32(x, 31);
    int bits = _mm_movemask_ps(_mm_castsi128_ps(x));
    res += bits << i;
}
```

The extension to AVX2 is pretty obvious.

An other possible approach is shifting each lane by a variable amount (pre-AVX2 this requires multiplication) and then summing, first vertically of course, saving the horizontal sum for last. This is likely slower, and certainly more awkward.